# Should I use try-catch or throws custom exception or both while reading property file in Java?

Tags: java, exception

I am reading properties from property file in the classpath of my project.

```
public Properties readFileFromClasspath(String fileName) throws MyException {

    Properties props = new Properties();
    InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName);
    if (inputStream != null) {
        try {
            props.load(inputStream);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new MyException("Could Not read properties from file  : [" + fileName + "].",e);
        }
    } else {

        throw new MyException("Could Not find property file  : [" + fileName + "] in the classpath.");
    }
    return mainProperties;

 }
```

Here `MyException` simply extends `Exception`.

Should I use **try-catch** or **throws MyException** or **both**?

Comment: Depends. Can your application continue without loading this file? If not, you definitely need to either close the application, or throw an Exception.
If it's "optional" to have the file, don't bother the rest of the application, and write your code so that it can continue without it, maybe by providing a default set of Properties to be returned if this fails.

Comment: You could use neither and simply add IOException to the method signature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are loading application properties during startup from a fixed-name properties file I would throw an undeclared, unchecked exception:

```
    public void readApplicationProperties() {
        this.properties = readFileFromClasspath("application.properties");
    }

    private Properties readFileFromClasspath(String fileName) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName);
        if (inputStream == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not find property file: [" + fileName + "] in the classpath.");
        }
        try {
            props.load(inputStream);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not read properties from file: [" + fileName + "].", e);
        }
        return props;
    }
```

My reasoning is that the application cannot recover from this error so there is no point creating a custom checked exception, catching it, etc. In the end the application will have to terminate with a meaningful error message. The simplest way to do this is with an unchecked exception.

Answer (score 0):

Depends. Can you load default properties if there is an exception? In that case catch the exception, load default properties and warn in a log.

If there is impossible to load application without properties, you must thrown an exception.

You have to decide whether your exceptions can be controled or not.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are free to choose, but in both cases, you should always be as much informative as possible when throwing. In this case, I see no reason to create a custom exception. I'd throw `IOException` if something bad happens while reading the properties file, otherwise `FileNotFoundException` if the properties file is not there. If you want to read more, [here](http://www.journaldev.com/1696/java-exception-handling-tutorial-with-examples-and-best-practices) is one of the many tutorials you can find about exception handling.

Answer (score 0):

I think sometimes we over do it with the exceptions, to me your code should only verify the file exists and throw a FileNotFoundException, other than that why throw the exception that is already being thrown?  You're not doing anything special in the catch.